# Can't update extension in chrome web store, no errors

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I've been struggling to get my update to go through. I incremented my version in the manifest and updated a lot of code, I upload the new package successfully and submit, but I never see the manifest version update in the chrome web store and there are no errors. The draft of the package always shows the same version as well (0.0.0.1 as I have never had a successful update). When I submit the status goes to pending and then public.

My only guess is that something is wrong with my account. This update includes moving from manifest v2 to v3 as well although I feel like I'd get an error if something was wrong there.

I've tried to resubmit this multiple times over the past 3 weeks and always the same lack of update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a few .pem files in a random node module. I hadn't realize I should just remove node_modules from the zipped up package, but for some reason it only errored out and warned me about including .pem files sometimes. Most of the time updating the package seemed to work fine and didn't error. Very strange. Regardless it is fine now!